# C code after preprocessor

Tags: c

This is an exercise taken by a book. The question is what is the output of this code.

This code prints always "N is undefined", but I don't know why. The command "#undef N" is after the function f. Then, why the output is always "N is undefined"?

```
#define N 100
void f(void);

int main(void)
{
    f();
    #ifdef N
        #undef N
    #endif
    return 0;
}

void f(void)
{
    #if defined(N)
        printf("N is %d\n", N);
    #else
    printf("N is undefined\n");
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The point of this exercise is to demonstrate that preprocessor's control flow is completely separate from the control flow of your program.

`#if`/`#undef` directives are processed in the order that they appear in the text of your program. They are processed only once at compile time; the decision to define or undefine a preprocessor variable cannot be reconsidered at runtime.

That's why the fact that `f` executes before `#if`/`#undef` line of the `main` is irrelevant. You can change the output of this program only by moving `f` to a position in file *before* `main`.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the compiler with the -E flag (for gcc at least) it'll show you what the code you're actually compiling is.

You'll see that the preprocessor doesn't follow the code execution - it performs its actions in the order that they appear in the file.

Then the compiler takes the resulting code and `f` just has the one call to `printf` in it that says N isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

The C preprocessor goes through your code line by line. As such, it is wrong to assume the `#undef` happens after the function `f()` because of the function call. Instead, it happens before your definition of function `f()`.

To understand this, you have to distinguish between the preprocessor (line by line) and the control flow (follows function calls).

Answer (score 0):

Because the preprocessors instructions run in the "physycal" order, line after line.

Think about it something is executed before actual compilation, in a such way your code be clear, only with plain C code for the compiler.